# Inequality that could be used here (Hölder is forbidden) :)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, inequality

I would like to know if there are finer inequalities to separate an integral of a product of functions, i.e. Imagine we have two functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $fg\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Then
$$\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)g(x)dx\right|\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)g(x)|dx \leq \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|^p dx\right)^{1/p}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}|g(x)|^q dx\right)^{1/q}$$
where $1/p+1/q=1$ and we can even include the case $p=\infty$ using the essential supremum.

Is there a better way to split the further most LHS into two type of different norms of $f$ and $g$ which is better than Hölder's inequality? Are there other finer inequalities known?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: This is exactly Hölder's innequality is it not ?

Comment: You may prove Holder's inequality through Young's inequality, or, proving first that the $L^p$ norm is a continuous function with respect to $p$, through Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and density of dyadic fractions.

Comment: I forgot: through Jensen's inequality, too. What is at your disposal?

Comment: I do not want to prove Hölder's inequality. I am just wondering whether there is an intermediate inequality between the middle integral and the RHS (i.e. Hölder). Another way to separate $f$ and $g$ without using Hölder which is "finer".